# How can I print 1 to 10, except 3 using while loop? I want to write that in Python code

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop

```
range = 10
```

i=1
while i < range:
print(i)
i += 1

Is there any way use 'continue statement' and make it happen?

Comment: No, but you can us an `if` to say to print if i is not equal to three.

Comment: Try to avoid using `range` as your variable name - as it's a special `builtin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use FOR statement

```
for i in range(1,11):
    if i!=3:print i
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method is this:

```
rng= 11
i = 1
while i < rng:
    print(i)
    i+=1
    if i ==3:
        i+=1
```

so when i = 3, it skips that i - I don't think you would need anything more complex than this

output is:
1
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

Comment: No problem - if my solution has solved your query, could you mark it as complete/accepted and up-vote it so that if others have a similar issue they know that this is the answer that solved it?

Answer (score 0):

```
while i < 10 :
   if i != 3 :
       print(i)
   i+=1
```

Comment: @TheDarkifY: If this solved your problem, please be certain to accept it as the answer when you’re able to. You can do that by clicking the check mark next to the answer. That will mark your question as resolved.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 